# Android - Longitude and Latitude from GPS vs From the Network

Tags: android

I've ran into a little problem and I don't feel like I'm informed enough to overcome the hurdle.

In essence, I'd like to figure out whether someone is moving over a threshold of say, 40 kmh (~25mph). I get GPS coordinates at designated intervals and compare the distances, which all works fine.

My question is, which method of getting GPS coordinates would work best for this application? Using the Network, using GPS, or both (like, check if the network is connected, else use GPS)?

The summary is, which is the most accurate method?

Comment: GPS > All else, usually. Since the rest use approximate locations whilst GPS is dedicated at giving you positioning data (with a certain error margin).

Comment: I would have thought so as well. I believe the accuracy is 8-12 feet or something, which is fine given a long enough time between 2 points. If you make this the answer, I'll check it off. Thanks!

Comment: I posted my comment as an uninformed possible answer. I did some light research and found that officially there is no claim to which method is better, possibly hardware dependent. All locational retrieval methods I've read recommend accessing through an API which automatically uses an aggregate of said methods, depending on a set of criteria. Fused location API seems to be a good way forward.

Comment: I would probably just check for either GPS or Network;

Comment: GPS all the time. Network is inaccurate.

Comment: I've got a check to see if GPS is enabled `isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`, but it seems to always be false, even when I can clearly see that my GPS is enabled. Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the fused location api in this case. In addition, if you want to know if someone is moving you could use the activity recognition of google play services, it requires much less effort and you can even filter by activity: only with car for example (if you want to track over the 40km/h it's unlikely someone is moving on feet).